# gcc options: pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0

Tags: c, gcc, sh, pkg-config

I am trying to learn gtk and following this link : http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/firstprograms/ I was able to get a basic program to run. The way to compile the code was to use the command:

```
gcc -o simple simple.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

I want to understand what the flags `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` mean.

I tried searching the man page for the flags `pkg-config`, `--libs` and `--cflags`, but couldn't find them. I would feel fairly satisfied if I understood what that snippet of text inside the *``* actually means.

Comment: not good and may fail. not with gtk. real thing is `gcc simple.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\` -o simple`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile a program using GTK+ 3.0 you need to provide compile options to tell the compiler where to look for include files and library files.

You can either specify them directly with the appropriate compiler options.
Or you can use the flags that were configured when you installed the GTK+ packages.
These flags can be retrieved using `pkg-config` command.

Putting the command in `` causes the content to be executed and being replaced by the output of the command.
This will provide the compile flags (`--cflags`) and library options (`--libs`) needed to build your application.

Comment: I see, so pkg-config is something that linux recognizes and spits out information that you ask for about a package, and when run with the flags --cflags and --libs it spits out exactly the information required for the c compiler to compile the program. Presumably this info is fed into pkg-config when gtk is installed.
also I typed in "pkg-config --libs --cflags" into the terminal and it spits out a large list of directories with a -I prepened at the start, which I assume is how one tells the c compiler where to find library files.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. A link to pkg-config manual was provided by user xing in comment below your question.